# OpenSessionInViewFilter and custom spring DAO

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions

I've coded a custom generic DAO in this way:

```
public abstract class DAOImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements DAO<T, PK> {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
protected Logger log = null;

private Class<T> type;

public DAOImpl(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public PK insert(T o) {
    return (PK) getSession().save(o);
}
....
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public Session getSession() {
    return SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, Boolean.FALSE);
}
}
```

All BO operations are transactional.

web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>HibernateFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.foo.bar.util.filters.MyOSIVFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
    <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
```

MyOSIVFilter is a subclass of OpenSessionInViewFilter that closes sessions in this way:

```
public void closeSession(Session session, SessionFactory sessionFactory){

    session.flush();
    super.closeSession(session,sessionFactory);
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory name="foo">

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">XXXXXXXXXX</property>

    <property name="show_sql">yes</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
```

beans.xml (extract)

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="read*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="query*" read-only="true"/>
                    <tx:method name="insert*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="java.lang.Throwable" />
```

simple code

```
public void queryBusiness(){
    MyObject obj = objDAO.find(111);
    insertProcess1(obj);
    insertProcess2(obj);
}
```

The problem: multiple Hibernate sessions are opened. Logs show OpenSessionInViewFilter opens a new session but, who is getting the other ones?

Comment: Just point out that Struts2 is used in project

Comment: Is the session factory used for the openSessionInViewFilter and the one in the DAO the same?

Comment: Please paste your hibernate config here...

Comment: Yes Ralph. In web.xml I have not parametrized the session factory bean name, so according to API, sessionFactory is looked for (and this is the name I have defined on beans.xml). I've completed the code in my post

Comment: Is `insert` in your `tx:attributes` list of `tx:method`s?  Otherwise it won't be folded into the transaction.

Comment: Yes A lee. I've pasted more lines for beans.xml.

Comment: Any reason you use REQUIRES_NEW as propagation instead of like MANDATORY or REQUIRED? I believe you will have one transaction open through OpenSessionInViewFilter but you explicitly refuse to use this transaction and request a new one for each insert.

Comment: Yes and no. I have multiple REQUIRES_NEW but this is the desired behaviour. I mean, I have a read-only method calling several requires-new methods; once I've read object X, it can not be passed through all methods because following uses are considered from different sessions. No sessions are created explicitly in the code; it seems some settings are causing to create a new session after the commint on first propagation-new transaction/method. I've added this code in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I might be wrong, but as I recall it once Hibernate gets to creating a new transaction it creates a new session as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Spring gets to creating a new transaction it creates a new session as well. I've seen many people having the same problem. For example look here:

http://www.jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/beware_propagation_requires_new_with

Comment: Thanks Julkiewicz! It gives the answer to the problem, but do you know which would be the correct way of using/coding the same behaviour? Related to my code, what would be the correct use of "obj" to allow using it all along the queryBusiness method, being aware off all changes on it after every method? May it be a pattern problem? Thanks a lot, it'been a headache for me ;)

Comment: As somebody else mentioned REQUIRES_NEW isn't really the way to go unless you want to just halt the current activity for a moment and do something totally different. But even if it were not for the new sessions, if you are inside a transaction and another transaction comes along, you probably won't see its results from the original one, unless you have ISOLATION_LEVEL < REPEATABLE_READ. Even if you do it's very unwise to depend on it. Therefore maybe try to refactor the code so that it uses PROPAGATION_REQUIRED nevertheless.